# Can I pay my friends Booking.com reservation using my own debit card at check in?

Tags: hotels, payment-cards, booking.com

I have recently booked a hotel with my friends card through booking.com. She will not make it to the hotel for check in time and I know booking.com doesn’t charge your card right away. They say it’s just a way to secure your room.

Can I use my own debit card at check in to pay the full amount? If so will booking.com charge her card still being said her card is on file with booking.com?

Comment: Whose name is on the booking?

Comment: She needs to contact the hotel and add you on the booking, otherwise you will not be able to check in.

Comment: The hotel room is under my name

Answer (score 8):

There are roughly two types of reservations with booking.com. The reservation which is paid upfront. In that case it's clearly stated when booking the accommodation. If so, then your friend's creditcard will be charged. The other type of booking is the one where you pay upon check-in or check-out. You're free to choose which payment method you use (off course only those accepted by the hotel). If you're not showing up, the hotel might charge your friend's creditcard though. Based on your description, your reservation would be payable upon arrival. You can thus pay with your own card.

If you're not sure if upfront payment applies to the booking, just give booking.com a call. In my experience, they're always happy to help.

Comment: Even if the room was pre-paid, if you call the hotel, a lot of hotels will happily let you cancel the reservation without a fee and re-book with a new card (because it gets them out of paying Booking.com a kickback).